# reportportal.io port to 8080

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reportportal

Im new to docker and reportportal.io and when i do the following command below.

sudo docker-compose -p reportportal up -d --force-recreate

Its trying to create a containter for port 8080 which is being used by jenkins. I received no error at all on my mint machine.

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                                      NAMES
678d7741cbc4        reportportal/service-analyzer:4.3.0                       "/service-analyzer"      50 seconds ago       Up 37 seconds       8080/tcp

So what i did is change anything in the yml file that has 8080 to 8083 but still its using that port. How do i get around this?

Comment: I can’t seem to add a lot of text here but I’m using this one

https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

you need to change only **gateway** exposed port

```
  - "8080:8080" # HTTP exposed
```

change it like

```
  - "8080:9090" # HTTP exposed
```

see codeline here:
https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L69

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not doing the port mapping correctly inside the docker-compose.yml file. Please share the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful if share docker file.
Try to run it like this docker-compose -p 8080:8083 -d --force-recreate
refer the following [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)